# Laravel lmutator $this->attributes return 'Undefined index: id'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm trying to add an attribute (rating) to a model.

So far I did this:

```
    public function getRatingAttribute()
    {

        return $this::join('reviews', 'accounts.id', '=' , 'reviews.account_id')
        ->where('accounts.id', $this->attributes['id'])
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(reviews.rating) / COUNT(reviews.id)'))->pluck('rating');
    }
```

But it returns `Undefined index: id`

The strange is if I do a `dd` on `$this->attributes` it shows all array attributes, including `id`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the attribute value?

Comment: You should be able to use $this->id instead of $this->attributes['id']

Comment: When I try to use `$this->id` it returns `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try leveraging the relation and just select the aggregate.

```
public function getRatingAttribute()
{

    return $this->reviews()
        ->selectRaw('AVG(reviews.rating) as aggregate')
        ->pluck('aggregate');

}
```

Update: Changed this to use the built in AVG to avoid the divide by zero.

Comment: @robarelli is a nice answer aswell, but I took this one on my code.

Comment: Agreed, but the reason I wouldn't do what @robarelli has done is that creates a collection only to grab the aggregate.  This won't scale well and could result in some performance issues in the future. I based my answer on a blog post by [Jarek at SoftOnSofa here](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/).

Comment: Do you realize this will run a separate SQL query for every model separately?

Comment: Absolutely. That is the way Eloquent stuff seems to work most of the time.  If limiting queries is the goal you might look into retrieving them all through a join separately from the model.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify using built-in relationships, then you don't have to worry about handling the attributes manually.

e.g.

```
public function reviews()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}

public function getRatingAttribute()
{
    return $this->reviews->count() > 0 ? $this->reviews->sum('rating') / $this->reviews->count() : 0;
}
```