# Laravel: Order mysql extracted data by mutator

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mutators

On [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380495/laravel-lmutator-this-attributes-return-undefined-index-id/32384869) I (we, because you guys helped me) did a mutator to add a column to the results I get from database.

Now my issue is: how can I order the results by the created attribute?

There is it:

```
public function getRatingAttribute()
{

    return $this->reviews()
        ->selectRaw('AVG(reviews.rating) as aggregate')
        ->pluck('aggregate');

}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the previous question, if it contains useful information. Also, it would be best to rephrase this in the form of a question so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Sean. I added the info as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

DB can't sort it for you as mutator data is fetched after the main sql request is already done. You need to sort the results in php using Collection methods, e.g.`$my_results->sortByDesc('rating');`

If you need to use a pagination then it is a big problem and you'll probably be better off using a join than mutators for this.